# Increase speed of animate() with every click()

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need a button that will increase the speed of my animation with every click.

At the moment I am trying:

```
function move(){
  var speed = 5000;
  $('img').animate({
    'left':'+=50'
  }, speed, move);
  $('li').click(function(){
    speed -= 4000;
  }); 
};
move();
```

But that doesn't seem to do anything. What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is even though the click handler changes the value of `speed` every call to `move` resets it to the the initial value of 5000, also there will be multiple click handlers registered since the method `move` is called many times

Try

```
function move() {
    var speed = 5000;
    function animate(){
        $('img').animate({
            'left': '+=50'
        }, speed, animate);
    }
    animate();
    $('li').click(function () {
        speed -= 4000;
    });
};
move();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/nzYX4/)

Comment: This makes the animation stop.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer it is because since you are reducing 4000 after the second click the speed becomes a negative value